# Vector gets only last value from Member

Tags: android, arrays, listview, vector

i am trying to add textviews from a text file using Vector
but i am encountring a problem.
when setting up my array that takes the information with Tokenizer, i print the values of
"mName" and it gets all the values from the text file.
but when i assing the "mName" to the TextView, i only get the last Name from the list..

here is the code:

Array and TextFile initialize - :

```
AssetManager assets = mContext.getAssets();

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                assets.open("country_list")));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(sCurrentLine,
                    ",");
            int count = 0;

            String[] stringArr = new String[3];

            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String tokenOrginizer = tokenizer.nextToken();
                stringArr[count] = tokenOrginizer;
                count++;
                mVector = new Vector<Country>();

            }

            Country country = new Country(stringArr[0],
                    Integer.parseInt(stringArr[1]),
                    Integer.parseInt(stringArr[2]));
            mVector.add(country);
            System.out.println(stringArr[0]);
            for (int i = 0; i < mVector.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Vector : " + mVector.get(i).getmName());  
                //here i see all the values when printing
            }
```

GetView method - :

```
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mVector.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int itemId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv;
    if (convertView == null) {
        tv = new TextView(mContext);
    } else {
        tv = (TextView) convertView;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mVector.size(); i++) {
        tv.setText(mVector.get(i).getmName());
        // i have a feeling that this is where i do something wrong

    }

    return tv;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal that you see only the last item in the `Vector` as each time the `getView` method is called you set the text in a `for` loop iterating over **all** the values in `mVector`(and the last text you set for the `TextView` is the last value in the `Vector`). So, instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mVector.size(); i++) {
        tv.setText(mVector.get(i).getmName());
        // i have a feeling that this is where i do something wrong
        // your feeling is right, why the loop?!?  
}
```

you'll want:

```
//...
if (convertView == null) {
    tv = new TextView(mContext);
} else {
    tv = (TextView) convertView;
} 
tv.setText(mVector.get(position).getmName());
return tv;
```

Also, use an `ArrayList` instead of the `Vector`.